# How to Convert epoch this format "MM/DD/YYYYHH:mm:ss"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unix, timestamp, epoch

i select calendar and set "1517380775843" console , i try convert and get format = 20180131093935 GMT+03:00 ,not now time i try select time and convert to human readable data pls help . thanks

```
<DateTimeField onChange={this.clock} format={"x"} inputFormat={"YYYY/DD/MM HH:mm:ss"}/>

     clock=(newDate)=>{    

            console.log(newDate)
    }
```

Comment: dates have methods, like `toDate` `toMonth` `toFullYear` `toHours` `toMinutes` and `toSeconds`

Comment: Or look at the moment js library (https://momentjs.com/) - this has lots of utilities for handling/formatting date and time.

Comment: @MarkWilliams my problem isn't formatting , is convert

Comment: Sorry - didn't understand, thought you had a date value (1517380775843) and wanted to to format it. What are the values you wish to convert?

Answer (score 0):

Use moment JS to do such operations.
For example:

```
moment.parseZone(element.requestDate).format('DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm A')
```

or for converting to a format specified:

```
moment(dateString,'DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm A')
```

Visit https://momentjs.com/ for the docs